# 3 variable Kmap into 2-1 Mux

Tags: multiplexer

I am trying to figure out if I implemented a 2-1 Mux correctly based on  a 3 variable K-map.

my function states F(x,y,z)=  Σm(0,1,3,6), and I have created a kmap as follows

```
  00  01  11 10
```

0]     1  ,  0,  1 , 0

1]     1 , 1 , 0 , 0

Note: the most sig bit is x,and xy are the top inputs and z is the side inputs

from this I found that a 2-1 Mux could be implemented by using z as my selector and ~b=0 and ~a=1, as my inputs to be pushed.
Is this correct or have I done this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,it's right.You can use z as your selector pin.Here's how finally it's look like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8qtGn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you give z=0,the top portion of K-map will be active.That is 00 and 11,for z=0,the output is 1.

  Similarly when z=1,the output F=1 for x=0 (after some simplifications)